# Vs code randomly skips lines when I type down an Identifier

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, tags

```
<
```

#randomly shifts whatever I type down here

I'm supposed to type 
But it ends up looking like

```
<
div > < /div>
```

Comment: Wrong file type most likely

Comment: what formatter you are using?

Answer (score 0):

I guess it is vs code setting for auto close tags.

try to disable it and check if it is fixed or not.

**Go to File > Preference > Setting ( Ctrl + , ) Extension > HTML. And remove tick from the "Auto Closing Tags".**